# Get date of a given day of the week based on current date Carbon Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

Based on the current date `Carbon :: now ()`, there is a need to get the date from the current week by the ordinal number of the day of the week from 1 to 7 or by the name of the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday ...).

Example:

- Let's say the current date is 2020-12-12;
- There is a need to find out what date will be for Sunday of the current week by the name Sunday or by the number of the day of the week 7;

Comment: new Carbon('this sunday');

Comment: are you receiving day from external resource

Comment: @Thomas I didn't think it would be so easy but it works) Thank you!

Comment: all the best man